# How does one play multiple sounds simultaneously on XAudio2?

Tags: c++, windows, xaudio2

I am currently trying to make a game app in Windows with XAudio2 and I cannot figure out how to make the application not block when playing a sound. I tried calling a new thread in the samples in [this repository.](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/XAudio2)

But it will just cause an error. I tried passing a reference to the mastering voice in the function but then it just raises a "XAudio2: Must create a mastering voice first" error. Am I missing something? I am just trying to make it play two sounds at once and build from there. I went over the documentation but it's very vague.

Answer (score 3):

XAudio2 is a non-blocking API. To play two sounds simultaneously, you need two 'source voices' and one 'mastering voice' at a minimum.

```
DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    CoInitializeEx( nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED )
);

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IXAudio2> pXAudio2;
// Note that only IXAudio2 (and APOs) are COM reference counted
DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    XAudio2Create( pXAudio2.GetAddressOf(), 0 )
);

IXAudio2MasteringVoice* pMasteringVoice = nullptr;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    pXAudio2->CreateMasteringVoice( &pMasteringVoice )
);

IXAudio2SourceVoice* pSourceVoice1 = nullptr;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    pXaudio2->CreateSourceVoice( &pSourceVoice1, &wfx ) )
    // The default 'pSendList' will be just to the pMasteringVoice
);

IXAudio2SourceVoice* pSourceVoice2 = nullptr;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    pXaudio2->CreateSourceVoice( &pSourceVoice2, &wfx) )
    // Doesn't have to be same format as other source voice
    // And doesn't have to match the mastering voice either
);

DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    pSourceVoice1->SubmitSourceBuffer( &buffer )
);

DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    pSourceVoice2->SubmitSourceBuffer( &buffer /* could be different WAV data or not */)
);

DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    pSourceVoice1->Start( 0 );
);

DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    pSourceVoice2->Start( 0 );
);
```

> You should take a look at the samples on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/XAudio2) as well as [DirectX Tool Kit for Audio](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Audio)

If you wanted to ensure both source voices started at precisely the same time, you'd use:

```
DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    pSourceVoice1->Start( 0, 1 );
);

DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    pSourceVoice2->Start( 0, 1 );
);

DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    pSourceVoice2->CommitChanges( 1 );
);
```

Comment: So does that mean that a different thread is assigned to play a sound for each source voice?

Comment: No. There's one audio thread that does the 'mixing'. It takes input from all active source voices and processes the 'audiograph'. The mastering voice submits the single audio stream to WASAPI for output. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xaudio2/xaudio2-audio-graph)

Comment: Thank you. It works a little bit differently compared to other code, because here you can actually have multiple sounds using up the sourceVoice->Play() method simultaneously (in other words multiple sounds playing at the same time) without any data races. ie there's apparently no need for you to use threads or other synchronization mechanisms. As you said, XAudio2 and WASAPI handles this stuff for you behind the scenes. (just spelling it out)

Comment: Effectively every call you make to an ``XAudio2`` API is asynchronous and will be acted upon by the audio thread in the next quantum. The main trick is that the application must keep all memory buffers pointed to by the queued buffers in all XAudio2 source voices valid until after they finish playing. This model allows audio to be responsive (glitches are easily heard), and avoids the need to copy the source voice data into private buffers--which is what DirectSound did.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play multiple sounds simultaneously have a `playSound` function and launch various threads to play your various sounds each one of a certain source voice.

XAudio2 will take care of mapping each sound to available channels (or if you have a more advanced system you can specify the mapping yourself using `IXAudio2Voice::SetOutputMatrix`).

```
void playSound( IXAudio2SourceVoice* sourceVoice )
{
    BOOL isPlayingSound = TRUE;
    XAUDIO2_VOICE_STATE soundState = {0};
    HRESULT hres = sourceVoice->Start( 0u );
    while ( SUCCEEDED( hres ) && isPlayingSound )
    {// loop till sound completion
        sourceVoice->GetState( &soundState );
        isPlayingSound = ( soundState.BuffersQueued > 0 ) != 0;
        Sleep( 100 );
    }
}
```

For example to play two sounds simultaneously:

```
IXAudio2SourceVoice* pSourceVoice1 = nullptr;
IXAudio2SourceVoice* pSourceVoice2 = nullptr;

// setup the source voices, load the sounds etc..

std::thread thr1{ playSound, pSourceVoice1 };
std::thread thr2{ playSound, pSourceVoice2 };

thr1.join();
thr2.join();
```